# Recommended way to do paging in mysql when count matters

Tags: mysql, sql, paging

I have a MySQl suggestion table like this

```
id:int
user_id:int
item_id:int
```

and I wanted to implement paging for the most suggested items by users. assume each page size is 9. so i have tried

```
   select count(id) as total,item_id from suggestions group by item_id order by total desc limit 9;
```

which simply works for the first page and returns

```
+-------+---------+
| total | item_id |
+-------+---------+
|     6 |       4 |
|     6 |       8 |
|     6 |      16 |
|     5 |       5 |
|     5 |       6 |
|     5 |       1 |
|     3 |      17 |
|     2 |       3 |
|     2 |       7 |
+-------+---------+
```

in second page i wanted to show the results from total = 2 and item_id =2. In SQL server i can use  `Row_number()` method to number the rows for paging. But i can't find something like this in MySQL.

am new to mysql, can somebody help me out.

see the attached the sample data below

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | item_id | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       4 |       1 | 2011-04-18 05:21:08 | 2011-04-18 05:21:08 |
|  6 |       5 |       2 | 2011-04-18 07:28:25 | 2011-04-18 07:28:25 |
|  8 |       5 |       3 | 2011-04-18 08:10:46 | 2011-04-18 08:10:46 |
|  9 |       4 |       4 | 2011-04-18 12:58:17 | 2011-04-18 12:58:17 |
| 10 |       4 |       5 | 2011-04-18 13:24:59 | 2011-04-18 13:24:59 |
| 11 |       4 |       6 | 2011-04-18 13:28:28 | 2011-04-18 13:28:28 |
| 12 |       4 |       7 | 2011-04-18 13:30:20 | 2011-04-18 13:30:20 |
| 13 |       8 |       5 | 2011-04-18 13:42:30 | 2011-04-18 13:42:30 |
| 14 |       8 |       6 | 2011-04-18 13:42:44 | 2011-04-18 13:42:44 |
| 15 |       8 |       4 | 2011-04-18 13:42:52 | 2011-04-18 13:42:52 |
| 16 |       9 |       5 | 2011-04-18 13:44:34 | 2011-04-18 13:44:34 |
| 17 |       9 |       6 | 2011-04-18 13:45:23 | 2011-04-18 13:45:23 |
| 18 |       9 |       7 | 2011-04-18 13:46:28 | 2011-04-18 13:46:28 |
| 19 |       9 |       1 | 2011-04-18 13:46:29 | 2011-04-18 13:46:29 |
| 20 |       4 |       8 | 2011-04-18 13:58:38 | 2011-04-18 13:58:38 |
| 21 |       8 |       8 | 2011-04-18 13:59:39 | 2011-04-18 13:59:39 |
| 22 |       9 |       8 | 2011-04-18 14:00:47 | 2011-04-18 14:00:47 |
| 23 |       8 |       1 | 2011-04-18 14:03:58 | 2011-04-18 14:03:58 |
| 24 |       4 |       9 | 2011-04-19 10:24:38 | 2011-04-19 10:24:38 |
| 25 |       4 |      10 | 2011-04-19 10:54:13 | 2011-04-19 10:54:13 |
| 26 |       4 |      11 | 2011-04-19 10:57:10 | 2011-04-19 10:57:10 |
| 27 |      12 |       8 | 2011-04-19 11:33:02 | 2011-04-19 11:33:02 |
| 28 |      12 |       4 | 2011-04-19 11:33:18 | 2011-04-19 11:33:18 |
| 29 |      12 |       1 | 2011-04-19 12:07:51 | 2011-04-19 12:07:51 |
| 30 |      12 |       6 | 2011-04-19 12:09:05 | 2011-04-19 12:09:05 |
| 31 |      12 |      12 | 2011-04-19 13:07:35 | 2011-04-19 13:07:35 |
| 32 |       9 |      13 | 2011-04-19 13:29:17 | 2011-04-19 13:29:17 |
| 33 |       9 |      14 | 2011-04-19 13:45:56 | 2011-04-19 13:45:56 |
| 34 |       9 |      15 | 2011-04-19 13:49:08 | 2011-04-19 13:49:08 |
| 35 |      14 |      16 | 2011-04-19 16:47:28 | 2011-04-19 16:47:28 |
| 36 |       4 |      16 | 2011-04-19 16:49:46 | 2011-04-19 16:49:46 |
| 37 |      13 |      16 | 2011-04-19 16:50:29 | 2011-04-19 16:50:29 |
| 38 |      15 |       5 | 2011-04-19 16:53:55 | 2011-04-19 16:53:55 |
| 39 |      15 |      16 | 2011-04-19 16:54:15 | 2011-04-19 16:54:15 |
| 40 |      15 |       8 | 2011-04-19 16:54:29 | 2011-04-19 16:54:29 |
| 41 |      15 |       4 | 2011-04-19 16:58:20 | 2011-04-19 16:58:20 |
| 42 |      15 |       0 | 2011-04-19 16:59:21 | 2011-04-19 16:59:21 |
| 44 |       9 |       4 | 2011-04-19 17:03:54 | 2011-04-19 17:03:54 |
| 45 |       9 |      16 | 2011-04-19 17:03:57 | 2011-04-19 17:03:57 |
| 46 |      13 |       8 | 2011-04-19 17:08:56 | 2011-04-19 17:08:56 |
| 47 |      13 |       6 | 2011-04-19 17:08:58 | 2011-04-19 17:08:58 |
| 48 |      13 |      17 | 2011-04-19 17:10:26 | 2011-04-19 17:10:26 |
| 49 |      18 |      16 | 2011-04-19 17:15:49 | 2011-04-19 17:15:49 |
| 50 |      18 |       4 | 2011-04-19 17:15:52 | 2011-04-19 17:15:52 |
| 51 |      18 |       1 | 2011-04-19 17:15:53 | 2011-04-19 17:15:53 |
| 52 |      18 |       5 | 2011-04-19 17:15:54 | 2011-04-19 17:15:54 |
| 53 |      18 |      17 | 2011-04-19 17:15:57 | 2011-04-19 17:15:57 |
| 54 |      19 |      17 | 2011-04-19 17:21:45 | 2011-04-19 17:21:45 |
| 55 |      19 |      18 | 2011-04-19 17:22:28 | 2011-04-19 17:22:28 |
| 56 |      22 |      19 | 2011-04-19 17:35:40 | 2011-04-19 17:35:40 |
| 57 |      26 |      20 | 2011-04-19 17:46:00 | 2011-04-19 17:46:00 |
| 58 |      26 |      21 | 2011-04-19 17:51:51 | 2011-04-19 17:51:51 |
| 59 |      26 |      22 | 2011-04-19 17:54:32 | 2011-04-19 17:54:32 |
| 60 |      26 |      23 | 2011-04-19 18:11:24 | 2011-04-19 18:11:24 |
| 61 |      26 |      24 | 2011-04-19 18:12:23 | 2011-04-19 18:12:23 |
| 62 |      27 |       2 | 2011-04-19 18:24:38 | 2011-04-19 18:24:38 |
| 63 |      27 |      25 | 2011-04-19 18:29:07 | 2011-04-19 18:29:07 |
| 64 |      27 |      26 | 2011-04-19 18:31:51 | 2011-04-19 18:31:51 |
| 65 |      27 |       3 | 2011-04-19 18:32:46 | 2011-04-19 18:32:46 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
select count(id) as total,item_id from suggestions 
group by item_id order by total desc 
limit 9 offset 9;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for MySQL, however I'd like to point out that for MyISAM storage engine this has severe performance implications when there's millions of rows and offsets are high. Even though Sam's suggestion is correct, I'd recommend the following link for getting insight in optimization of LIMIT OFFSET in MySQL - http://explainextended.com/2011/02/11/late-row-lookups-innodb/

Comment: yep thats what i am looking for.. :)